# Meteor - Slow loading with large dataset

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm working with quite large data in MongoDB and using it in my Meteor application. However, the size of the data is causing the webpage to load incredibly slowly.

The collection is around 17MB in size and contains 84,000 documents.

[image: Collection]

Using the Publish/Subscribe method I have the following code:

Imports -> Both -> MyCollection.js:

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

export const statistics = new Mongo.Collection('statistics');
```

Server -> Main.js:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { HTTP } from 'meteor/http';
import { statistics } from '/imports/both/MyCollection';

Meteor.publish('statistics', function publishSomeData() {
  return statistics.find();
});
```

Client -> Main.js:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';
import { statistics } from '/imports/both/MyCollection';
import './main.html';

Template.application.onCreated(function applicationOnCreated() {
  this.subscribe('statistics');
});

Template.application.onRendered(function applicationOnRendered() {
this.autorun(() => {
    if (this.subscriptionsReady()) { 
      const statisticsData = statistics.findOne();
      console.log(statisticsData);
    }
  });
});
```

So like I say this method works and the console logs the data. However, using an internet connection of around 60mbps it takes around 2 minutes to load the page and finally console log the data and sometimes I just get the 'Google is not responding' alert and I'm forced to force quit.

What is a more efficient means of loading the data into the application in order to avoid this terribly slow loading time? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,

G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limit the amount of data you publish to the client.

Either only publish some fields of the statistics collection or 'lazy load' documents - pass a number of docs argument to the publication and use the  `limit` option of find to only send that many docs to the client.

Alternatively, compile the data as needed on the server and only send the compiled data to the client.

Much more specific examples cannot be given without knowing the collection's nature.

Comment: If you think any of these solutions may work, I can provide snippets to demonstrate their implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Seb. My issue is all the documents need to be available to me in the application so only publishing partial amounts of data wont work for me. Lazy loading sounds like an appropriate option for me if you have an example I could see that would be great! Thank you

Comment: There's a good example [here](https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/web_development/9781783988129/4/ch04lvl1sec41/lazy-loading-posts). It has a couple of quick sections with a 'next section' button at the bottom of the page. Does that explain the pattern clearly?